# cant create create-service in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Start read the cloud-native-java book.
Where according to guide. Try to create service using the command:

```
cf create-service p-mysql 100mb bootcamp-customers-mysql
```

in result i have an error:
**`**Service offering p-mysql not found**`**

What is the wrong ?

Comment: Contact Cloud Foundry's support [help-support](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/help-support/)

Comment: **Service offering p-mysql not found** - Service is not available from marketplace. If you are trying with Pivotal Web Services, check with cleardb service offerings.

Answer (score 3):

You can always run `cf marketplace` to see what services are available to you. `p-mysql` is the service created by the MySQL Tile for Pivotal Cloud Foundry and as was mentioned in the comments, is not available in PWS or other hosted CF offerings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cleardb` service (if you are using PWS) here is a sample for that:

```
> cf create-service cleardb spark bootcamp-customers-mysql
```

where `spark` is a plan for service